# How to improve performance of remote rendering?

Tags: remote-desktop, nvidia-graphics-card, vnc, nvidia-geforce, vncserver

I have PC in the office which is running Ubuntu and has GeForce RTX 2080. I also have laptop at home which is running Windows. In order to benefit from nvidia card from home I've started TurboVNC server on remote machine and I'm connecting there. However performance is poor and I don't know if bottleneck is my network connection, some configuration or something else.

Here are my **glmark2** benchmark results:

1. 14 000 when running benchmark from the office (GeForce RTX 2080 GL renderer is used)
2. 1 000 when running benchmark remotely (llvmpipe GL renderer is used)
3. 120 when running benchmark remotely but starting TurboVNC with -vgl parameter (GeForce RTX 2080 GL renderer is used)

I understand that performance is worse with llvmpipe GL renderer, since I guess HW acceleration is not used in that case but I don't understand the last case, since glmark2 reports that nvidia card is used but performance is horrible. Is it because of network? Would it work comparable to first case if my VPN connection was a lot better? Is there anything I can do to improve performance when working remotely?

**Edit:**
I've rerun case 3 in better network conditions (8 times faster) but result was the same, so network is not bottleneck here.

Comment: It's almost certainly bottlenecked by the network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if this is indeed network problem then shouldn't glmark2 run at full speed achieving score arround 14 000 as in first case just I would be seeing slideshow? Or is benchmark waiting for me actually receiving the frames?